# Regex to replace function name in PHP classes

Tags: regex, sed, grep, pcre

I'm converting a PHP5 application to PHP7, and one of the requirements is to remove all instances of a constructor having the same name as the class, and instead to give it the name "__construct".

So for example:

```
class xyz {
    public function xyz() {
```

needs to become

```
class xyz {
    public function __construct() {
```

I figured egrep piped into sed might be the best way to do this "en masse", but I don't know either well enough to do so.

I know I can use:

```
class\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+\{
```

to capture the name of the class, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

:)

Comment: Is using a scripting language (e.g. `PHP`) an option?

Comment: It is, I'd just rather not reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, better use a scripting language, some logic and a two-factor-approach:

1. Match the class including the class name as "a whole" using a recursive approach
2. Replace the function with the class name with `__construct`

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

$class_regex = '~
        ^\s*class\s+
        (?P<class>\S+)[^{}]+(\{
        (?:[^{}]*|(?2))*
        \})~mx';

$data = preg_replace_callback($class_regex, 
    function($match) {
        $function_regex = '~function\s+\K'.$match['class'].'~';
        return preg_replace($function_regex, '__construct', $match[0]);
    },
    $data);

echo $data;
?>
```

See a demo for the outer regex on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hzzzkz/1/) and for the whole [**code on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/aLpfBh).